# visual studio 2010 asp.net gridview is not a known element

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I am using VS2010 Pro with SP1.  For some reason its complaining about all my Gridview controls and nothing else.  I do not see any errors in the markup.

So far I have tried 2 things

1. Following the instructions here http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/fix-validation-element-not-supported-visual-studio-2010
2. Deleting my solutions .suo file

Neither of these are working.  I still keep getting the same problem.  All I find via google are hundreds of people having the same problem with all sorts of different controls.

Are there any more things I can try ?

Thanks,

Steed.

Comment: What is VS saying in the complaint?

Answer (score 0):

It appears on the 3rd try of deleting the "ReflectedSchemes" folder, the problem went away.  Thanks anyway.